# Select the same option multiple times / onchange without changing

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a select, and I need to fire some js each time an option is selected, even if it is already selected.
Example:

```
<select id="select_one">
    <option value="">Choose One...</option
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

If someone selects "one" I want to fire functionOne().  But, while "one" is selected, if the user selects "one" again I want to fire functionOne() again.  So, that means onChange won't work, since the selection isn't changing.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "selects one again"? If you mean just clicking/focusing the selected option the answers below are what you need (hook the onclick event) otherwise explain what you mean..

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to some of the current answers, you don't actually get a `click` event on `<option>` in IE.

The only reliable way to detect the case of an option being clicked that was already selected is to put the `onclick` handler on the `<select>`. Naturally this will also detect any other clicks on the select element, so depending on what `functionOne()` is doing this may not be safe either.

You might be better off with something that looks like a select but isn't, such as a pop-up div with buttons on it. What is it you are trying to do? If you're trying to do a “jump menu” where selecting an option navigates to a new page: *don't*, it's an old and discredited mechanism with serious usability problems.

Answer (score 0):

add onClick to the `<option>` tag

Answer (score 0):

after firing the onSelect, change the select value to "Add Another"?
eg. forst option has an id of #selectBox, value of '' and a html of "Select One".
onChange, retrieve the value `$('#selectBox').val();`  and turn around after your actions and go `$('#selectBox').val('').html('Select Another');`

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` even to each option tag. Inside the function do:

```
function() {
  var timesClicked = $(this).attr('times-clicked') || 0;
  $(this).attr('times-clicked', ++timesClicked);
  if (timesClicked == 1) {
    functionONe();
  }
  else if (timesClicked == 2) {
    functionTwo(); // and so on
  }
}
```